# How to detect if user deleted text in input box

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <!-- When a user clicks a key provide info on the key clicked -->
        <form action="#" id="sampForm">
            <input id='charInput' type="text">
            <p id="keyData">Key Data Here</p>
        </form><br /><br />

    </body>

<script>

    function getChar(event) 
    { 
      // event.which returns the key or mouse button clicked
      if (event.which == null) {
        // Return the char if not a special character
        return String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode); // IE
      } else if (event.which!=0 && event.charCode!=0) {
        return String.fromCharCode(event.which);   // Other Browsers
      } else {
        return null; // Special Key Clicked
      }
    }

    var all = '';

    document.getElementById('charInput').onkeypress = function(event) 
    {
      var char = getChar(event || window.event)
      if (!char) return false; // Special Key Clicked

      // document.getElementById('keyData').innerHTML = char + " was clicked";
      all += char;
      document.getElementById('keyData').innerHTML = all;
      return true;
    }

</script>
```

And I tried to do the following:

```
document.getElementById('charInput').onkeypress = function(event) 
    {
      var char = getChar(event || window.event)
      if (!char) return false; // Special Key Clicked

      // document.getElementById('keyData').innerHTML = char + " was clicked";
      all += char;
      document.getElementById('keyData').innerHTML = all;
      return true;

      if ( ( (document.getElementById('charInput').value).length) == 0 ) 
      {
            all = '';
      }

    }
```

What I tried to do is to check the length of the input box and if the length is zero it should reset the variable all. 
But it still doesn't work. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `document.getElementById('keyData')`. You don't have an element called keyData in your markup, so you can't set its innerHTML. Check your browser console when you're running the code, it would have shown you this error and the line it occurred on. Also using `char` as a variable name is risky because some standards have it as a future reserved word (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar).

Comment: Why do you have : `if (!char) return false; // Special Key Clicked`, as the delete key _is_ a special key ?

Comment: try document.getElementById('charInput').onchange= function(){ //then check the length }

Comment: @ADyson Thanks, I added it. The variable name is just for test but thanks for mentioning, I didn't know that.

Comment: @CCH I deleted that line and it stills doesn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `keyup` event and just check the if the `value.length` is zero

```js
function getChar(event) {
  // event.which returns the key or mouse button clicked
  // Return the char if not a special character
  if (event.which === null) return String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode); // IE
  else if (event.which !== 0 && event.charCode !== 0) return String.fromCharCode(event.which); // Other Browsers    
  return null; // Special Key Clicked
}



document.getElementById('charInput').onkeyup = function(event) {
  if (this.value.length === 0) {
    alert('Empty');
    // variable resetting here
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="#" id="sampForm">
  <input id='charInput' type="text">
</form><br /><br />
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that sorted it out.

Answer (score 1):

`keypress` fires *before* the value in the textbox is changed. try listening for `keyup` :

```
document.getElementById('charInput').onkeyup = function(event) 
{
      //...
}
```